# PostgreSQL slow query log entries contain no query details, only duration

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, slow-log, troubleshooting

I have a PostgreSQL RDS instance hosted in AWS. I have set the `log_min_duration_statement` setting to 1 second. When checking my log for slow queries I found the following six entries which don't contain any query/statement:

[image: slow query log]

Does anyone have any idea why this happened? How can I find out which slow queries caused these log entries?

**UPDATE** Thanks to jjanes for pointing me in the right direction. I found that the "log_statement" option causes duration and statement to be logged separately. Here it is in Postgre docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT

[image]

Comment: Is the statement text being hidden by your applied filter?

Comment: @jjanes no the filter is just looking for "duration:" text, it wouldn't block any text from appearing in individual events

Comment: @jjanes i'll check but that's not how Postgres slow query logging works. It always includes the duration and statement on the same line.

Comment: Not when `log_statements='all'`.  Or when set above none, but less than all, for the cases where it does kick in.

Comment: @jjanes yes you're right that log_statements option is set to 'all' currently....what does that mean exactly for the slow query logs? How can I differentiate between those log entries? Thank you!

Comment: With that setting, the text of the query is logged when the query begins, and the duration (only) is logged when it ends. You can use the PID or maybe the client IP and port number to pair those up in the log file.  I don't know if RDS provides a specific way to do that, I've always done it in `vim` or `less`.  But really, I just auto_explain now.  I think that this is available in RDS although I've never used it there.

Comment: @jjanes thank you for your help, I think this is the solution. if you'd like to post it as such, i'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With log_statements='all', the text of the query is logged when the query begins, and the duration (only) is logged when it ends. You can use the PID or maybe the client IP and port number to pair those up to each other in the log file. I don't know if RDS provides a specific way to do that, I've always done it in 'vim' or 'less'.

But really, I just [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) now. I think that this is available in RDS although I've never used it there.

Answer (score 0):

You may have `log_duration` set to `on`.
If so, changingit to `off` should allow you to get statements with your `log_min_duration_statement` set to `1`.

Comment: No it's not on. These are the only log entries showing a duration.

Comment: Unless RDS did some weird hacking here, setting `log_duration = on` does not suppress the output of `log_min_duration_statement`, rather the opposite.  (But setting `log_statements='all'` does cause the statement to be logged on a different line than the duration, which might cause it to be overlooked)

Comment: @jjanes, what you wrote is totally true, depending on the way RDS is performing log parsing would have an effect on what is shown on the log output. My point was to disable the  `log_duration` to remove duration only output and see what was going on. If both settings are turned on, there might be some double duration output that might confuse (maybe) the AWS parser.

Comment: Good point.  Thanks for the clarification.